# problem with treeview

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, treeview

I want to configure the tree view component so that would be the topmost parent node would have no chex box and all the others had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/947aaded-6372-4253-8799-2b595f4a39b9 (the main idea is to handle `DrawNode` for nodes)

Comment: i have the problem with using delegates on managed-c++. Help with this string on managed-c++
this.treeView.DrawNode += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawTreeNodeEventHandler(this.treeView_DrawNode);